# ElasticSearch filter on array of terms is filtering out all terms

Tags: filter, elasticsearch

In my application, users belong to a list of roles and objects have a list of roles associated with them to determine visibility.  I'm trying to create a query that ensures the user belongs to at least one of the groups that is required by the object.

Here is my index configuration:

```
{
    "settings": {
        "analysis": {
            "filter": {
                "nGram_filter": {
                    "type": "nGram",
                    "min_gram": 2,
                    "max_gram": 12,
                    "token_chars": []
                }
            },
            "analyzer": {
                "nGram_analyzer": {
                    "type": "custom",
                    "tokenizer": "whitespace",
                    "filter": [
                        "lowercase",
                        "asciifolding",
                        "nGram_filter"
                    ]
                },
                "whitespace_analyzer": {
                    "type": "custom",
                    "tokenizer": "whitespace",
                    "filter": [
                        "lowercase",
                        "asciifolding"
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
   },
    "mappings": {
        "team" : {
            "dynamic": "strict",
            "properties" : {
                "id": {
                    "type": "string",
                    "index": "not_analyzed"
                },
                "object": {
                    "type": "string",
                    "index": "not_analyzed"
                },
                "roles": {
                    "type": "string",
                    "index": "not_analyzed"
                },
                "name": {
                    "type": "string",
                    "index_analyzer": "nGram_analyzer",
                    "search_analyzer": "whitespace_analyzer"
                },
                "text": {
                    "type": "string",
                    "index_analyzer": "nGram_analyzer",
                    "search_analyzer": "whitespace_analyzer"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here is some sample data that I have indexed:
(verified via localhost:9200/index/_search?q=name:employee_1&pretty)

```
{
    "id":"lsJ17K4sgQVfd",
    "roles: ["OwnerslsJ17K21px6VX","AdminslsJ17K21px6VX"],
    "object":"contact",
    "name":"employee_1",
    "text":"lsJ17K4sgQVfd employee_1 employee_1 employee_1@lsj17k1nysk75.com"
}
```

Here is my query that I am trying to execute to find that same contact:

```
{
    "_source": ["id", "object", "name"],
    "size": 30,
    "query": {
        "filtered": {
            "query": {
                "bool": {
                    "should": {
                        "multi_match": {
                            "query": "employee_1",
                            "type": "cross_fields",
                            "operator": "or",
                            "fields": ["name^2", "text"],
                            "minimum_should_match": "50%",
                            "fuzziness": "AUTO"
                        }
                    },
                    ...,
                    "minimum_should_match": 1
                }
            },
            "filter": {
                "terms": {
                    "roles": [ "AdminslsJ17K21px6VX", "lsJ17K3gHCH4P" ]
                }
            }
        }
    },
    "suggest": {
        "text": "employee_1",
        "text_suggestion": {
            "term": {
                "size": 3,
                "field": "name",
                "sort": "score",
                "suggest_mode": "missing",
                "prefix_length": 1
            }
        }
    }
}
```

If I remove the `filter` clause then I get results, but as soon as I add it back everything gets filtered out again.  What is the right way to express that I want the results to have at least one role in common?

Answer (score 0):

The query above works as expected, the only problem was that my test case was executing before the index was fully populated.  Adding a short wait time before making my first query solved the problem.